# Groupby aggregation with restricted imports using Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, variables, pyspark

I have dataframe **current** as below:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|   sid|acc_term_id|first_name| last_name|major|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|106454|      2014B|     Doris|  Marshall|  BIO|
|106685|      2015A|      Sara|Richardson|  CHM|
|106971|      2015B|      Rose|    Butler|  CHM|
|107298|      2015B|     Kayla|    Barnes|  CSC|
|107555|      2016A|   Carolyn|      Ford|  PHY|
|107624|      2016B|     Marie|      Webb|  BIO|
```

I am using below code :

```
 current.createOrReplaceTempView('current')
count = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM current")
tot = count.first()[0] 
display(current.groupBy('major')
          .count()
          .select(round(('count')/('tot'), 4).alias('prop'))
          .orderBy('prop', ascending=False))
```

to get the result:

```
+-----+----------+----+
|major|n_students|prop|
+-----+----------+----+
|  BIO|         2|0.33|
|  CHM|         2|0.33|
|  CSC|         1|0.17|
|  PHY|         1|0.17|
+-----+----------+----+
```

Code is not working and return some error of not recognizing variable **tot**.

Any ideas how to perform this task by importing only:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: you're dividing two strings in python... did you mean round(F.col('count')/tot, 4)?

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your approach: First you don't get the total numbe rof rows with `tot = count.first()[0]` and second you'll combine `.count` and `select` in the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you @pythonic833. The problem is I need to use only imported libraries as shown and cannot import F

Comment: @user1997567: why do you have this restriction? Then you need to do all this with `expr`

Comment: @pythonic833 I tried this.agg(
    expr('COUNT(*) AS n_students')
    
    )
    .select('major', 'n_students', expr('ROUND(n_students/c_value, 4) AS prop'),
    ) but it throws error not finding ROUND func

Comment: @user1997567 see the update to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate the number of rows and then do a groupBy.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

tot= df.count()

df.groupBy('major').count()\
    .withColumn('tot_count', expr(f"{tot}"))\
    .withColumn('prop', expr('round(count / tot_count, 4)'))\
    .select('major', col('count').alias('n_students'), 'prop').show()
```

which results in

```
+-----+----------+------+
|major|n_students|  prop|
+-----+----------+------+
|  CHM|         2|0.3333|
|  CSC|         1|0.1667|
|  BIO|         2|0.3333|
|  PHY|         1|0.1667|
+-----+----------+------+
```